# Police laser speed detection guns

Tags: visible-light, wavelength

#### Situation

Police shooting a [laser device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIDAR_speed_gun) into his rearview mirror, bouncing off the oncoming car license plate.   I want to know if this second surface mirror, and the symmetric system--laser gun to mirror to license plate of moving car to mirror to laser gun---has a built in error because of the wavelength shift due to the glass of the mirror.  Velocity and wavelength change for the raypath inside the mirror's glass,  but would revert to the original wavelength for the "in air" portion of the raypath.

#### Question

Is this symmetry perfect and creates no error in measuring the car's speed?

Comment: I think it is a safe presumption that *if* there is an error, it's been accounted for in the calculation of the speed.

Comment: Nope. If the police laser gun says that you drove too fast, you can bet your license on it, that you did. And so will the judge.

Comment: I'm also hoping that you're not planning on using us as a defense!

Comment: @KyleKanos: He is most welcome to, it just won't help him. :-)

Comment: There is, of course, an angle dependent error term. The larger the angle between the car's velocity vector and the laser beam, the SLOWER the readout will be. So if the gun says that someone was driving 85mph, then they were actually driving FASTER than 85mhp...

Comment: @Brad, is the link I added of the correct type of speed gun?

Answer (score 3):

Any waves that appear on one side of an interface must immediately leave on the other side.  There's no room to queue them up.  This means that in a frame where the interface is at rest, the frequency on both sides is always the same.

Once you have that, then it becomes obvious that the wavelength in air will always be the same as well.  So from the automobile's view, the glass doesn't add any error to the reflected wavelength.  It could add a total time component to the reflection, but I don't believe that is used by speed equipment.

---

Well, the wiki article added to the question states that at least LIDAR units do use "time-of-flight" rather than doppler measurements.  If true, the wavelength issue would not matter.  Internal reflection in a window could (slightly) increase the reflection time, but you would expect it to be nearly constant over different measurements.  Any added time would be minimal and would cancel out.

Comment: +1: Yes on both counts. Frequency is unchanged by passing through a refractive medium - as you say, you can't "queue" the wave fronts. And yes, LIDAR uses time of flight, but speed is determined from successive time of flight measurements, taking out the constant component. So the mirror does not matter.

Comment: For practical reasons, I think police **radar** guns rely on Doppler shift within a pulse, while police **laser** guns relay on pulse-to-pulse time of flight differences.  Both phenomena rely on the fact that the range to the target is changing over time.  So neither of these methods would be affected by bouncing the signal off a mirror that is stationary with respect to the gun.  In the case of the pulse-to-pulse time-of-flight technique, all the pulses might be delayed by the mirror, but by the same amount, so the difference wouldn't be affected.